# Check for duplicates in a text form field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a VBA noob and I'm trying to compare the numbers entered in a text form field in ms word, then if a duplicate is found I display a msg box.

The problem I'm having is... I have to compare 33 fields and look for a duplicate of anywhere from 1 to 33. I'm receiving a message that the procedure is too large. I'm sure there must be an easier way to do this. It's a protected document which I unprotect once the user hits the command button. I've even tried breaking it up and assigning macros to some of the fields.

Here is a sample of what I have. There are 33 bookmarks and I'm comparing each field.

```
If (ActiveDocument.FormFields("s1").Result = "1" And _
ActiveDocument.FormFields("s2").Result = "1") Then
MsgBox ("Your preferences cannot be duplicated.")
 Validate = True
    If True Then Exit Sub
  Else
    Validate = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub CompareFormfields()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .FormFields.Count - 1
    For j = i + 1 To .FormFields.Count
      If (.FormFields(i).Type = wdFieldFormTextInput) And (.FormFields(i).Type = wdFieldFormTextInput) Then
        If .FormFields(i).Result = .FormFields(j).Result Then
          MsgBox "The data in FormField " & i & " is duplicated in FormField " & j
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
End With
MsgBox "Done checking"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and was stuck in a loop, so I added 'If True Then Exit Sub, Else Validate = False'. This snapped it out of the loop, however it doesn't seem to be reading the text that is actually put in the form field.... it just thinks everything is duplicate lol. Thanks for your assistance though!

Comment: @CourtneyMiller The code works just fine for me and does not get stuck in a loop. The only reason you'd get a result where "everything is duplicate" is if you're testing empty formfields. Even then, though, the formfield references will progress.

Comment: thanks for your help! I did get this to work after I made minor alterations and changes to other items that I had coded to check for different things.